# 'No such interface supported' when attempting to compress file through 7zip commandline

Tags: windows-7, command-line, zip, 7-zip, pipe

When I run the 7zip commandline:

```
> echo foo | 7za a arc.7z -sifoo.txt
```

Everything works as expected, but if I try to do:

```
echo foo | 7za a arc.zip -sifoo.txt
```

I get the following:

```
E:\7zip>echo foo | 7za a arc.zip -sifoo.txt

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Creating archive arc.zip

Compressing  foo.txt    0%

System error:
No such interface supported
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Don't know if the applies here or not but (Note: The current version of 7-Zip support reading of archives from stdin only for xz, lzma, tar, gzip and bzip2 archives.)

Comment: supposed to say -tzip though I still get the error echo foo | 7z a -tzip r.zip -sifoo

Comment: and probably supposed to put switches between command and archive name, though still get the error. but no doubt you should use -tzip for zip.  So this works for example, no echoing though >7z a -tzip r.zip a.a   But doing >echo text | 7z a -tzip -sia.a r.zip  gives the error. so your question stands. And you mean 7z a, not 7za.